# Browser doesn't display uploaded image until intelij gets focus

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea, thymeleaf

I have this weird problem with displaying pictures using intellij-idea in a spring boot application using thymeleaf as template engine.
SO far, I'm able to upload the image, but, it gets displayed ONLY when I give Idea focus, meaning, Idea doesn't refresh the images folder when not on focus.
Before this, I was not able to show the image at all unless I restart the server, but after I set the policy "On frame deactivation" I'm able to display the newly uploaded image, of course only after I give idea focus which triggers a refresh of images folder.

I have tried some other tips that change the value of a registry, and other that uses dev tools, but none of them worked as I want.

Is there a way to make Idea refresh its folders when changed without having window focus?
Or, can I solve this problem differently?

Thank you in advance for your valuable help.

This is the part that regards the display of the image

```
<img th:src="@{${user.imagePath}}"/>
```

imagePath represents the image path in DB
Example value: http://localhost:8888/images/users_pictures/user_image_5.jpg

I don't expect controller and service classes to be involved in this problem, since the image gets uploaded and displayed after all, but do not hesitate to ask me to provide additional source code that might affect the problem.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand what you're trying to do: why don't you test your application in a normal browser? How do you "upload" the image? Why would you expect the image to change? Is there some JavaScript that's polling the server or waiting for some websocket event or a page refresh after uploading?

Comment: Hi Thomas. My app simply adds users with profile pictures. When I add a new user, the user is added, and the picture is indeed loaded and saved in static/images folder, BUT, the browser doesn't show the picture (display picture with broken thumbnail). I have to go to my Idea (meaning the IDE gets focus) and that refreshes the images folder (the new user picture is added in intellij images folder), and when I go back to my browser and refresh it, the picture is displayed correctly. PS: No Javascript or any front-end framework is used.

Comment: My wild guess is that somehow this is related to IntelliJ's `Update classes and resources` on `On frame deactivation`. This might happen if you are uploading images to your project directory instead of war file directory. Considering images are only available from inside the war file, you are not able to see them until IntelliJ's `Update classes and resources` kicks in when IDE gets focus.

Comment: Hi Kedar. That's exactly my problem. Is there a way around it? Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Well, he's already hinted at the way around the problem: "This might happen if you are uploading images to your project directory instead of war file directory. " - Just _don't_ upload images to the project directory but use the war file directory instead. In production there won't be any IDE to run your application so you should build it as if there were non on your machine right from the start. Your software should _never_ depend on the IDE used to build it.

Answer (score 0):

As noted, the project directory is not the appropriate place to store images. (And probably not the deployed directory either if you want your pictures to persist between runs or deployments.)  Instead you should either:

1. Store the images in a database.
2. Store the images in a local directory accessible from where your application is deployed to.

In either case, you won't be able to rely on the resources servlet to supply your images.  You will have to create a controller that outputs the appropriate image (from the database or from the filesystem).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Getting them from the filesystem makes more sense. Because I'ma beginner, I just want to make sure I understood you well. When you say "Store the images in a local directory accessible from where your application is deployed to" you mean the server machine, right?

Comment: Yep, the server.